# Custom Background Image on Grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How would I go about setting a custom background image for a UITableView. The wrench in the works is that the table is a grouped style (rounded top corners for the first cell and rounded bottom corners for the last cell). I would like do this as much in code as possible without relying on images too much.

Ideally, here is the solution, but I have no idea if this will work or not:

1. Create one custom background image
2. Apply the same custom background image to every cell
3. Rounding occurs automatically because it is a Grouped table style
4. Profit.

Is this how it works (besides the profit part... I am an app developer, after all)? Do I need to re-think my approach or is this possible? How would do what I described (or another approach) in code specific to iOS 5+?

***Update***

Just to clarify a bit, the main question I'm asking is: Does the rounding still occur on the top and bottom cells even if you are using a rectangular image?

Comment: Could you not set UITableView's backgroundView to whatever you want?

Comment: The background image is specific to cells, not the whole table. There are varying amounts of data that might be in the table. It's not static. I don't think that would work in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think what you are saying is ok, but I suggest creating a unique cell layout in a .nib file and apply there the background. Then, with initWithNibName you can manage every cell at the UITableView's methods on the ViewController.

Comment: Here's my main question: does the rounding still occur on the top and bottom cells even if you are using a rectangular image?

Comment: I didn't tried to do so, but I think you can set it to be cropped like in IB